# Tomcat Connection Pool - tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, connection-pooling

Can tomcat connection pooling be restarted just like we do in other containers i.e Weblogic?
Or restart is the only rescue to restart the pool in tomca 7 and higher?

Answer (score 0):

No such feature has been impemented.

Comment: Thanks, so restart of tomcat instance is the only rescue!